# On Cordova 2.0 app - readAsText breaks on iOS6 ...

Tags: file, cordova, ios6

I'm working on a Phonegap/Cordova app, use Cordova 2.0, and after iOS 6 is available - we suddenly begun to experience a problem. It's in the readAsText method of the file object.

Here is the part of the code. We use the facebook SDK to release Facebook Single Sign-On, and so we have a file, written down in a folder. Then we attempt to read it and take the token from it.

And so - on iOS 4 and iOS5 it's working - i.e. you'll see the two alerts - 111 and 222. But on iOS6 the second alert doesn't happen. Or in other words - the onloadend callback never triggers, although I see that the file is there.

```
// start the file interaction:
window.requestFileSystem(

    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function(fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.root.getFile(

            "FacebookData/facebookData",
            null,
            function(fileEntry) {

                fileEntry.file(

                    function(file) {

                        alert('111');

                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

                            alert('222');

                            // do something with the file .. 

                        }; // end of onloadend

                        reader.readAsText(file);
                    },

                    fail
                ); // end fileEntry.file

            },
            fail

        ); // end getfile

    },
    fail

); // end window.requestFileSystem
```

The function "fail" doesn't trigger at all, and also - all of this is inside a try-catch - but it doesn't throw an exception too.

And also - on iOS 4/5 it happens only once, but on iOS 6 it happens several times, as if you've clicked several times on a button and then the code executes.

Has anyone met a bug like this?

Answer (score 2):

Known issue, apparently there is a fix there : 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1219

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-js/pull/22

But I didn't test it yet.

Comment: Great, lost a day trying to figure this out.